# Why doesn't jQuery return the correct border properties of a thead element, and is there a workaround?

Tags: jquery, css, border, css-tables

As demonstrated in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bg100/GwjM2/2/), jQuery's css function doesn't return the border width/style/color of a `<thead>` element in a simple table:

```
$("thead").css("border-top-width") // returns 0px
```

If I try the same thing on a div, it works fine:

```
$("div").css("border-top-width") // returns 1px (or whatever the border width is)
```

Why doesn't this work? Is there another way to get the border details? I'm using Firefox if that makes a difference.

Comment: Works fine on Chrome 25

Comment: Which browser are you using? I get 1px both times. I'm using Chrome 24.0.1312.57.

Comment: @FelixKing: Firefox... as mentioned in my question.

Comment: I guess that means it's a Firefox bug... know of another way to fetch the border details?

Comment: @BG100, which version of jQuery are you using? Is the `<table>` element that contains the `<thead>` styled with `border-collapse: collapse`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the last sentence...

Comment: something more unexpected here: http://jsfiddle.net/GwjM2/4/ i just put `border-top-width` to `10px` and added `th` in that and this alerted `5px` **in firefox 19**.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: jQuery v1.9.1. It is styled with `border-collapse: collapse` but I've also tried other values which make no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why doesn't this work?**

because your `<thead>` element is displayed has a pseudo element.

Make it 'display: block' and [border will appear](http://jsfiddle.net/a3NZn/)

```
thead {display:block}
```

**NOTA**: `Display:block` on tHead might have a side effect. Ask your doctor for recommendations about 'setting in float' a *browser* pseudo element. For experience, setting `display:block` on a `<tbody>` tag made it's inner content (tr td) floating left, so making the `<table width="100%">` didn't apply on inner `<td>` width.

Comment: Can't believe it was a simple as that!!! As long as `display: block;` doesn't have any adverse side effects then this is perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you still have troubles:

```
parseInt($("thead").css("border-top"))
```

Comment: Thanks, but sadly this doesn't work. It returns NaN. Also tried the same but using `border-top-width` and I just get 0 as before.